# Roulette wheel selection in GA: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, selection, roulette-wheel-selection

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531565/how-should-roulette-wheel-selection-be-organized-for-non-sorted-population-in-g) I've tried to do my roulette wheel selection in genetic algorithm.

```
private static final int NUMBER_OF_TOURISTS = 20;

private static int[] roulette(int population[]) {
    int sumProb = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
        sumProb += population[i];
    }

    int[] rouletteIndex = new int[NUMBER_OF_TOURISTS];
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TOURISTS; i++) {
        int numberRand = r.nextInt(sumProb);
//-------------------------------------------------------
        int j = 0;          
        while (numberRand > 0) {
            numberRand = numberRand - population[j];
            j++;
        }
        rouletteIndex[i] = j-1;
//-------------------------------------------------------
    }
    return rouletteIndex;
}
```

after this I get:

```
[6, 2, -1, 19, 13, 2, 14, 2, 6, 19, 7, 14, 18, 0, 1, 9, 13, 10, 7, 2]
```

"-1"? But how, when  j  should be always greater than 0.
Is this happen when numberRand = 0 and than while loop doesn't start even once? But how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[`Random.nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) returns 0 (inclusive) to specified bound (exclusive).

So your loop:

```
while (numberRand > 0) {
    numberRand = numberRand - population[j];
    j++;
}
```

Will not run if `nextInt(int bound)` returns 0, resulting in `j` being 0 at: `rouletteIndex[i] = j-1;`

Comment: Like I thought. I do simply: only if (j > 0) than j = j-1; else j = 0

Comment: Well inaccordance with the answer you linked your implementation makes sense. But the pseuocode doesn't make it clear what should happen when `r = 0`. I would suggest `rouletteIndex[i] = j == 0 ? 0 : j - 1;` as a quick fix.